# list index out of range - CodingBat Problem - Has22

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

Here's the problem.

This is part of the List-2

Medium python list problems -- 1 loop.

- Given an array of ints, return True if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.

  has22([1, 2, 2]) → True
  has22([1, 2, 1, 2]) → False
  has22([2, 1, 2])    → False

---

I was getting the error "list index is out of range" at first

I know where I was going wrong on line 4 of the original problem because once it is at the last number in the list it cannot add one anymore.

I have provided my original code below. The first code block was when I was getting the error "index out of range". The second solution works but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of writing it.

Also on CodingBat when I run my solution it says "Other Tests" Failed at the bottom but no example I'm not sure what that means.

Thanks

Here's my code block - FIRST TRY:

```
def has22(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        first = nums[i]
        second = nums[i+1]
    if first == second:
    return True
```

MY SOLUTION:

```
def has22(nums):
    size = len(nums)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        first = nums[i]
        if size >= i+2:
            second = nums[i+1]
        if first == second:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if the question is whether the solution can be written cleaner, I think something like this should work:

```
def has22(nums):
    return (2, 2) in zip(num, num[1:])
```

and it looks pretty clean.

A little bit of explanation - [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) creates pairs of values from 2 lists, so I just slice the input list into 2, where in the second list I omit the first element. Then I simply check whether tuple `2, 2` exists in the zipped pairs.

BTW I just noticed a bug in your solution - it returns `True` for input e.g. `[2, 1]` (basically any input, where `2` is second to last. So to fix this bug, and preserve the original "idea" of your solution, you could write it like this:

```
def has22(nums):
   for i, el in enumerate(nums):
       if el == 2 and i + 1 < len(nums) and nums[i + 1] == 2:
           return True
   return False
```

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is the preferred way of iterating through a list with indices.

Comment: Much thanks. I will have to study these methods. Thanks for the easier solution to this.                   Okay I see my bug because size is now not >= i+2 it cant run the code beneath it to assign a new number to the second variable. Which makes the if statement below run and lets the first variable "catch up" to the second variable and make them equal.                                                                                   I guess I could change this line as well if first ==second   to     if first == 2 and second == 2:    and I think that would fix it as well.